# Select Case statement - IF statement - define array - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, if-statement, case

I want to define new arrays according to the value of the age variable. I am new to VBA and here is my code that does not work. I have no error messages. I was wondering why the arrays do not get any value from this code!

```
Select Case num
   Case 24 To 55
       Arr_Num3554 = 1
        Case Else
       Arr_Num3554 = 0
   End Select

Select Case Num
   Case 54 To 75
       Arr_Num5574 = 1
        Case Else
       Arr_Num5574 = 0
   End Select

Select Case Num
   Case 75 To 100
       Arr_Num74plus= 1
        Case Else
       Arr_Num74plus= 0
   End Select
```

---

Also I have tried an IF statement. Again I have the same problem

```
If 24 < Num < 55 Then Arr_Num3554 = 1 Else Arr_Num3554 = 0
If 54 < Num < 75 Then Arr_Num5574 = 1 Else Arr_Num5574 = 0
If 75 < Num Then Arr_Num74plus = 1 Else Arr_Num74plus = 0
```

Comment: Why does your Case criteria overlap?

Comment: just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you use arrrays you need to redim (the array variable) -  ReDim Arr_Num3554(1)

Answer (score 1):

Does your code even compile?  Try this instead, and note @Lowpar's comment as well:

```
Select Case num
   Case 24 To 55
       Arr_Num3554 = 1
        Case Else
       Arr_Num3554 = 0

   Case 54 To 75
       Arr_Num5574 = 1
        Case Else
       Arr_Num5574 = 0

   Case 75 To 100
       Arr_Num74plus= 1
        Case Else
       Arr_Num74plus= 0

End Select
```